# Why can you never see other part of the ship through the windows on the Enterprise-D?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

In various scenes in Star Trek TNG will can see out of the windows. The Observation Lounge has a whole wall-full of windows. Then - why can you NEVER see other parts of the ship through the windows?

From the observation lounge, immediately behind the Main Bridge on Deck 1, you should see the top of the saucer section sloping gently away, the top of the Engineering section, and the nacelles. But you see none of this. Only space.

Another area is the shuttle-bays - with the door open, you should be able to see the external top of the saucer section just outside and the nacelles, but again, it's always just space.

Comment: I guess everyone on the Enterprise knows what the nacelles look like. There is little use in reminding them by displaying them day by day in the window. And stars are way more spaceyer, gives the crew a good "final-frontier-feeling"! And probably it's cheaper to produce...

Comment: I think 'cheaper to produce' is the real reason, your suggested in-universe reasons don't really do it for me

Comment: It's not obvious that you "should" see the saucer section sloping down away from below the bottom of the window, at least not unless you are standing at the window and aiming your eyes (or camera) at a downward angle. If your line of sight is a horizontal and you're not standing too near the windows (as with pretty much all shots of the windows in the observation lounge I think), what makes you think the saucer section would be visible?

Comment: Also not clear why you think you should see the "top of the saucer section" from the shuttle bays, since the shuttle bay doors face in the opposite direction from the top of the saucer, see labels 8, 11, 28 and 32 at http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints/galaxy-08.jpg (from http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/galaxy-class-starship.php )

Comment: The windows of the Obs Lounge go quite low, and they face out onto the almost horizontal upper surface of the saucer section. I'm sure it should have appeared an many shots. It'd be like looking out of a ground floor window - the ground would be clearly visible. Similar to the shuttle bays (at least shuttle bay 1) - just exterior to the door is a flat area, as clearly seen on the diagram. Since the floor of the bay itself is visible in shot, the flat area outside should also be visible. I think there probably is no in-universe answer, it is purely down to production costs or oversight.

Comment: Did a little googling and it seems you're right that the saucer would have been visible out the bottom of the window, as well as the top of the shuttlebay (not the nacelles though). Someone created a 3D model of the enterprise and posted a wireframe showing the view out of the observation lounge here: http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=237784&page=8 (it's post #110 by lewisniven)

Comment: Perhaps the shape of the transparent aluminum bends the light perspective upward so the crew gets a floating aimlessly in space appearance without physical reminders they're on a ship.

Comment: @BBlake Doesn't work. When on warp the stars are moving away from the window. If it would catch the light from the stars above, we would see the stars moving down the window. Maybe those windows are just view screens - like the one on the bridge. Then again: My initial theory (cheaper to produce) still feels more plausible to me.

Comment: Oh, I know that's the out of universe reason.  Special effects are very expensive, especially early in a show when they don't have much they can reuse.  Just trying to come up with a possible in-universe reason.  I don't think they're just viewscreens either.  You can see the windows from outside during exterior shots of the ship from above/behind.

Comment: @NickJ, the bottom of the Windows observation lounge windows aren't that low.  It looks to me to be about even or slightly above the height of the table or Troi's hips.  Which would put it somewhere in the 0.7-0.85 meter range.  The levels are a bit raised, so their might be a 2-3 meter drop before you see the low slowly sloping surface.

Comment: @BBlake: I was actually quite disappointed TNG remastered did not fix this in the observation lounge and the shuttlebay scenes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer is that this is indeed a production goof. As you can see from the quick'n'dirty wireframe animation I threw together, you **should** be able to see at least the top of the rear of the saucer section (but not the nacelles themselves) from the observation lounge windows.

No in-universe explanation is offered. This sort of production error is generally indicative of [Bellisario's Maxim](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim); the need to avoid examining a show too carefully and to recognise that...

> ...the story is being told by a small production team that (due to the
>   limitations of the medium) has to work quickly, with limited budget
>   and tight deadlines

[image] [image]

Comment: That's a pretty close match with the wireframe by larryniven at http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=237784&page=8 -- but I wonder, how much wiggle room is there in creating a 3D model from canon published deck plans? If you raised the floor (and the bottom of the windows) by a meter or two, would that make the saucer no longer visible from a seated perspective like in the video clip above?

Comment: @Hypnosifl - The short answer is no. Raising the horizon even a handful of degrees makes almost no difference in what you can see...

Comment: thanks, I had forgotten that raising the floor a few meters would also involve raising the height of the viewer by the same amount, so it wouldn't just be a matter of lifting the blue lines in the wireframe while keeping the Enterprise at the same visual position in that graphic.

Comment: Good answer, upvoted despite including Admiral Necheyev in the clip. She's not very nice!

Comment: @NickJ - She's just doing her job (and loving it).

Comment: Impressive animation! How did you do it?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I downloaded a mesh for the Enterprise-D from http://www.trekmeshes.ch/ and uploaded it into a mesh viewer (MeshMagic if memory serves), then used licecap to create an animated gif of what I was seeing on screen

Comment: And here I thought you reconstructed the mesh yourself ;) Very good thinking though.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I haven't got the patience for that  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but as for the Main Shuttlebay portion of the question, keep in mind that we've NEVER seen the interior of the E-D Main Shuttlebay. The closest we come is in "Cause and Effect", where we see into it a tiny ways from the exterior of the ship. Whenever we've seen characters in a shuttlebay or shuttles departing, it's always been in one of the smaller ones (because of the production limitations of the time). So those two are below the saucer section. Don't know why you wouldn't see the nacelles though.

Comment: It's not just the main shuttlebay; shuttlebays 2 and 3 are at the back of the "neck" that gently slopes down diagonally from the saucer. Whenever we see a shuttlebay [from the inside](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shuttlebay_2?file=GalaxyShuttlebay.jpg), the outer door appears to be in an absolutely vertical wall, and we always see it well at an angle. However, we never see anything outside, e.g. the inner side of a recession in the slope. This is geometrically pretty much impossible. (Not to mention the tractor beam in that image that comes from *somewhere* above.)

Answer (score 0):

That's more a aspect of where you are. Most of the time whose looking out is done on either the Observation lounge the angle of which you might see the hull of the ship if you were looking down and also the ready room which only has a window looking portside, or various crew quarters. The saucer section of the Enterprise-D is at a very acute angle, so much so that the windows are angled at nearly 45 degrees or less. decks 34-42 are also insanely acute angled they're practically skylights instead of windows. It may be difficult to look out at an angle for one, the windows might be several inches thick, as is the ships hull. The windows would function similar to an "Embrasure" like those of castles that permit looking out but are narrow to protect the establishment.
[image]